# BFTIODFTTWKBCSC

Tags: cipher

This is my first self-developed cryptographic puzzle. I hope it is neither too hard nor too easy for you to break, and that you enjoy it. Please do not only post the answer, but also your way towards it.

---

You are Alan Turing 2.0 - a British intelligence officer trying to break newly created codes from around the world.

Based on intelligence gained by turning a Zambian cipher clerk, you are right now listening in on a test run of a Zambian-Zimbabwian ciphered exchange, codenamed "Project Anaconda", using a newly developed cipher going by the cryptic name of "BFTIODFTTWKBCSC".

The cipher clerk delivered to you

- the name(s) of the cipher,
- the route used, so your technicians could listen in and report to you the text transmitted,
- that the cipher requires a key that the clerk does not get to see, but that to his knowledge only a single key has been agreed upon during a meeting by the three-star generals overseeing the whole operation,
- that his input terminal had 29 keys: the alphabet, the space, the apostroph and the enter key, and a mode switch to select "Encrypt" or "Decrypt", but neither Shift nor numeric keys.
- that most likely some standard phrases will be used in the test conversations.

No other useful information could be gained until now; the interrogator will report to you at once if he gains anything valuable.

The technicians reported that the line has gone live only after they tapped into it.

Your objectives:

- Decipher the test messages.
- Determine the key(s) used.
- Reverse-engineer the algorithm.
- Decipher the algorithm name.
- If possible, determine the respective country of the correspondents A and B.

The test messages reported by your technicians until now were the following:

> A: `XMVSDPNID_ZM`
> A: `__KOHZDDUP_BPVH`
> B: `DMUSDPUIH_ZI`
> B: `GE_CF_OMHBDIUO`
> A: `LVDU_WISW_G_TRTUQUHG_FW`
> B: `H_VFSU__ZDONNMMV__R_CYURJEBUEUHV_RDSKZTJGQ_`
> A: `__P_IQTGTJOEZUCI_UPXIPTBTAOIZDCC__PIIQTMTJODZUCT_UPOIPTPTAORZD`
> B: `FRICX_XKIVV__OIFJRJWI_GLXV_PSORO_RXSL_IO_VX_IOETGRLWI_VHVPOKRS__V_O_RW_MVPOARS_RV_OXRW_KOP_`
> A: `T_ZLWPSFGC_HZ_WWYPSV_GO__GP_ODBUOLBOO_GULGAJNXMIH_`
> B: `_ACRB_SU_HUQWIOVBTHH_EZ'S_O_DU_UTDCVFG_TA_OPBPYOW_BDRB_POC`
> A: `__PT_ZECGHDUQ_AITKBPDIYOH`
> B: `BOIV`
> A: `TSGE_LEDXJVF_TVSSWL_G`
> A: `RWR_T_HVHZUUJDAUVF_SVTX`
> A: `RBXOWSIFF_`
> B: `DXLS_SW_RIPZROUPU`

Good luck, Mr. Turing.

Comment: I assume the `_` represents a space?

Comment: @TrojanByAccident I have clarified some things about the input terminal. (Given that the transmitted ciphertext has to be reentered by a clerk for decryption, you may assume that the `_` represents a space for legibility reasons.)

Comment: Alright. Nice puzzle, btw

Comment: @Alexander Are you using any standard cipher or a self built one?

Comment: @Techidiot The cipher is a standard cipher with two "improvements" by me, because the standard cipher in itself is not suitable for a puzzle on this site. I sincerely believe the resulting algorithm can be broken using basic cryptanalysis and a bit of internet search.

Comment: Are they writing in English or Zambian?

Comment: Have any hints?

Comment: It would be nice to have some hint!

Comment: Would it be okay to assume that the conversation is in English? And, is they encryption symmetric?

Comment: that the cipher requires a key // that the clerk does not get to see, // but that to his knowledge only // a single key // has been agreed // upon during a meeting // by the three // star generals overseeing // the whole operation. That would be a nice rap. $(+1)$ :D

Comment: I spent several hours on this yesterday, no dice. Can we get any kinda hint, @Alexander?

Comment: Has a correct answer at *long* last been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 24):

**Solution**

> A: HELLO_LUSAKA
> A: CAN_YOU_HEAR_ME
> B: HELLO_HARARE
> B: LOUD_AND_CLEAR
> A: TEST_TEST_ONE_TWO_THREE
> B: THE_QUICK_BROWN_FOX_JUMPS_OVER_THE_LAZY_DOG
> A: BUFFALO_BUFFALO_BUFFALO_BUFFALO_BUFFALO_BUFFALO_BUFFALO_BUFFAL (yes, the last O is missing)
> B: JAMES_WHILE_JOHN_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_A_BETTER_EFFECT_ON_THE_TEACHER
> A: TIME_FLIES_LIKE_AN_ARROW_FRUIT_FLIES_LIKE_A_BANANA
> B: THAT'S_ONE_SMALL_STEP_FOR_A_MAN_ONE_GIANT_LEAP_FOR_MANKIND
> A: HOUSTON_WE_HAVE_A_PROBLEM
> B: HAHA
> A: SPIDER_PIG_SPIDER_PIG
> A: THE_TEST_WAS_SUCCESSFUL
> A: HARARE_OUT
> B: HEAR_YOU_TOMORROW

**Key**

> In alphabetical shifts, the key is BOBDPOE (Bob D. Poe?).
>  
> In numerical shifts, the key is 1 14 1 3 15 14 4.
>  
> I only needed the first 7 so there could be more.

**Countries of the participants**

> Lusaka is the capital of Zambia and Harare is the capital of Zimbabwe, so A is from Zimbabwe and B is from Zambia.

**Reverse-Engineered Ciphering Process**

> Let's encode "ABCDEFG". We start with the first letter.
>  
> `- A`
>  
> This is line one.
>  
> On the next line we are going to write the next two letters on either side of the A:
>  
> `-  A`
> `- B C`
>  
> "B C" is line two. You may be wondering why I am not just writing this as "BAC". That's because we are going to shift the "A" and the "B C" independently of each other.
>  
> Next we write "DEFG" between the previous letters.
>  
> `-    A`
> `-  B   C`
> `- D E F G`
>  
> Now each line has to be shifted by the corresponding letter of the keyword: B, O, B.
>  
> `-    A    [Shift by B]`
> `-  B   C  [Shift by O]`
> `- D E F G [Shift by B]`
>  
> becomes
>  
> `-    B    [Shift by B]`
> `-  P   Q  [Shift by O]`
> `- E F G H [Shift by B]`
>  
> We then read the message from left to right to obtain the ciphertext.
>  
> `-    B    [Shift by B]`
> `-  P   Q  [Shift by O]`
> `- E F G H [Shift by B]`
> `- EPFBGQH`

Now let's apply this to the original messages.

> `- HELLO_LUSAKA`
> `-        H     [Shift by B]`
> `-    E      L  [Shift by O]`
> `-  L   O   _ L [Shift by B]`
> `- U S A K A    [Shift by D]`
> `- XMVSDPNID_ZM`
>  
> `- CAN_YOU_HEAR_ME`
> `-        C        [Shift by B]`
> `-    A       N    [Shift by O]`
> `-  _   Y   O   U  [Shift by B]`
> `- _ H E A R _ M E [Shift by D]`
> `- __KOHZDDUP_BPVH`
>  
> `- HELLO_HARARE`
> `-        H     [Shift by B]`
> `-    E      L  [Shift by O]`
> `-  L   O   _ H [Shift by B]`
> `- A R A R E    [Shift by D]`
> `- DMUSDPUIH_ZI`
>  
> `- LOUD_AND_CLEAR`
> `-        L       [Shift by B]`
> `-    O       U   [Shift by O]`
> `-  D   _   A   N [Shift by B]`
> `- D _ C L E A R  [Shift by D]`
> `- GE_CF_OMHBDIUO`
>  
> `- TEST_TEST_ONE_TWO_THREE`
> `-                T        [Shift by B]`
> `-        E           S    [Shift by O]`
> `-    T       _     T   E  [Shift by B]`
> `-  S   T   _   O  N E _ T [Shift by D]`
> `- W O _ T H R E E         [Shift by P]`
> `- LVDU_WISW_G_TRTUQUHG_FW`
>  
> `- THE_QUICK_BROWN_FOX_JUMPS_OVER_THE_LAZY_DOG`
> `-                            T                [Shift by B]`
> `-                H                   E        [Shift by O]`
> `-        _               Q       U       I    [Shift by B]`
> `-    C       K       _     B   R   O   W   N  [Shift by D]`
> `-  _   F   O   X   _   J  U M P S _ O V E R _ [Shift by P]`
> `- T H E _ L A Z Y _ D O G                     [Shift by O]`
> `- H_VFSU__ZDONNMMV__R_CYURJEBUEUHV_RDSKZTJGQ_`
>  
> `- BUFFALO_BUFFALO_BUFFALO_BUFFALO_BUFFALO_BUFFALO_BUFFALO_BUFFAL (yes, the last O is missing)`
> `-                                B                               [Shift by B]`
> `-                U                               F               [Shift by O]`
> `-        F               A               L               O       [Shift by B]`
> `-    _       B       U       F       F       A       L       O   [Shift by D]`
> `-  _   B   U   F   F   A   L   O   _   B   U   F   F   A   L   O [Shift by P]`
> `- _ B U F F A L O _ B U F F A L O _ B U F F A L O _ B U F F A L  [Shift by O]`
> `- __P_IQTGTJOEZUCI_UPXIPTBTAOIZDCC__PIIQTMTJODZUCT_UPOIPTPTAORZD`
>  
> `- JAMES_WHILE_JOHN_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_A_BETTER_EFFECT_ON_THE_TEACHER`
> `-                                                            J                                [B]`
> `-                                A                                           M                [O]`
> `-                E                               S                   _               W        [B]`
> `-        H               I               L               E       _       J       O       H    [D]`
> `-    N       _       H       A       D       _       H     A   D   _   H   A   D   _   H   A  [P]`
> `-  D   _   H   A   D   _   H   A   D   _   H   A   D   _  H A D _ H A D _ H A D _ H A D _ A _ [O]`
> `- B E T T E R _ E F F E C T _ O N _ T H E _ T E A C H E R                                     [E]`
> `- FRICX_XKIVV__OIFJRJWI_GLXV_PSORO_RXSL_IO_VX_IOETGRLWI_VHVPOKRS__V_O_RW_MVPOARS_RV_OXRW_KOP_`
>  
> `- TIME_FLIES_LIKE_AN_ARROW_FRUIT_FLIES_LIKE_A_BANANA`
> `-                                T                   [Shift by B]`
> `-                I                          M        [Shift by O]`
> `-        E               _              F       L    [Shift by B]`
> `-    I       E       S       _       L    I   K   E  [Shift by D]`
> `-  _   A   N   _   A   R   R   O   W   _ F R U I T _ [Shift by P]`
> `- F L I E S _ L I K E _ A _ B A N A N A              [Shift by O]`
> `- T_ZLWPSFGC_HZ_WWYPSV_GO__GP_ODBUOLBOO_GULGAJNXMIH_`
>  
> `- THAT'S_ONE_SMALL_STEP_FOR_A_MAN_ONE_GIANT_LEAP_FOR_MANKIND`
> `-                                T                           [Shift by B]`
> `-                H                               A           [Shift by O]`
> `-        T               '               S              _    [Shift by B]`
> `-    O       N       E       _       S       M       A    L  [Shift by D]`
> `-  L   _   S   T   E   P   _   F   O   R   _   A   _   M A N [Shift by P]`
> `- _ O N E _ G I A N T _ L E A P _ F O R _ M A N K I N D      [Shift by O]`
> `- _ACRB_SU_HUQWIOVBTHH_EZ'S_O_DU_UTDCVFG_TA_OPBPYOW_BDRB_POC`
>  
> `- HOUSTON_WE_HAVE_A_PROBLEM`
> `-                H          [Shift by B]`
> `-        O             U    [Shift by O]`
> `-    S       T       O   N  [Shift by B]`
> `-  _   W   E   _   H  A V E [Shift by D]`
> `- _ A _ P R O B L E M       [Shift by P]`
> `- __PT_ZECGHDUQ_AITKBPDIYOH`
>  
> `- HAHA`
> `-   H  [Shift by B]`
> `-  A H [Shift by O]`
> `- A    [Shift by B]`
> `- BOIV`
>  
> `- SPIDER_PIG_SPIDER_PIG`
> `-              S        [Shift by B]`
> `-        P         I    [Shift by O]`
> `-    D       E   R   _  [Shift by B]`
> `-  P   I   G  _ S P I D [Shift by D]`
> `- E R _ P I G           [Shift by P]`
> `- TSGE_LEDXJVF_TVSSWL_G`
>  
> `- THE_TEST_WAS_SUCCESSFUL`
> `-                T        [Shift by B]`
> `-        H           E    [Shift by O]`
> `-    _       T     E   S  [Shift by B]`
> `-  T   _   W   A  S _ S U [Shift by D]`
> `- C C E S S F U L         [Shift by P]`
> `- RWR_T_HVHZUUJDAUVF_SVTX`
>  
> `- HARARE_OUT`
> `-       H    [Shift by B]`
> `-    A    R  [Shift by O]`
> `-  A   R E _ [Shift by B]`
> `- O U T      [Shift by D]`
> `- RBXOWSIFF_`
>  
> `- - HEAR_YOU_TOMORROW`
> `- -          H        [Shift by B]`
> `- -      E       A    [Shift by O]`
> `- -    R   _   Y   U  [Shift by B]`
> `- -  U  _ T O M O R R [Shift by D]`
> `- - O W               [Shift by P]`
> `- - DXLS_SW_RIPZROUPU`

**Reverse-Engineered Deciphering Process**

> It is horrendous to manually decipher with the key.
>  
> First you have to count the number of characters:
>  
> `T_ZLWPSFGC_HZ_WWYPSV_GO__GP_ODBUOLBOO_GULGAJNXMIH_`
>  
> We have 50 characters here. Now we have to map out slots for the characters based on that number (notice how skewed it is according to the length of the last line). The numbers are going from left to right.
>  
> `-                               2`
> `-               6                          3`
> `-       8               4              9       7`
> `-   4       2       0       8       6    1   5   9`
> `- 2   6   0   4   8   2   6   0   4   8 0 2 4 6 8 0`
> `-1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7 9 1 3 5 7`
>  
> We insert the ciphertext:
>  
> `- T_ZLWPSFGC_HZ_WWYPSV_GO__GP_ODBUOLBOO_GULGAJNXMIH_`
> `-                                U`
> `-                W                          A`
> `-        F               _              G       M`
> `-    L       H       V       _       O    L   N   H`
> `-  _   P   C   _   P   G   G   D   L   _ U G J X I _`
> `- T Z W S G _ Z W Y S _ O _ P O B O B O`
>  
> Finally we unshift each line by the corresponding letter of the key:
>  
> `- T_ZLWPSFGC_HZ_WWYPSV_GO__GP_ODBUOLBOO_GULGAJNXMIH_`
> `-                                T                   [Unshifted by B]`
> `-                I                          M        [Unshifted by O]`
> `-        E               _              F       L    [Unshifted by B]`
> `-    I       E       S       _       L    I   K   E  [Unshifted by D]`
> `-  _   A   N   _   A   R   R   O   W   _ F R U I T _ [Unshifted by P]`
> `- F L I E S _ L I K E _ A _ B A N A N A              [Unshifted by O]`
> `- TIME_FLIES_LIKE_AN_ARROW_FRUIT_FLIES_LIKE_A_BANANA`

**Reasoning**

> This is the result of many, many all-nighters. I have been working on this since I joined the site a month ago.
>  
> Most of the work was of course ruling out what it wasn't. I had to keep repeating Edison's quote to myself: "I have not failed. I've just found 10,000 ways that won't work."
>  
> **The first major breakthrough** was observing that taking the first of every two characters of certain lines, I would find repeated sequences, such as `__P_IQT...` becoming `_PITTOZC_PITTOZC_PITTOZC_PITTOZ`.
>  
> `FRICX_XKIVV__OIFJRJWI_GLXV_PSORO_RXSL_IO_VX_IOETGRLWI_VHVPOKRS__V_O_RW_MVPOARS_RV_OXRW_KOP_`
>  
> becomes
>  
> `FIXXIV_IJJIGX_SR_XLI_XIEGLIVVOR_VOR_VOR_VOR_O_`
>  
> **The second major breakthrough** was observing that, with the above line, if I took the first of every two letters, then took the second of every two letters, then stitched these together,
>  
> `FIXXIV_IJJIGX_SR_XLI_XIEGLIVVOR_VOR_VOR_VOR_O_` + `RC_KV_OFRW_LVPOORS_OV_OTRW_HPKS___WMPASR_XWKP`
>  
> then removed `VOR_VOR_VOR_VOR`,
>  
> `FIXXIV_IJJIGX_SR_XLI_XIEGLIV_O_` + `RC_KV_OFRW_LVPOORS_OV_OTRW_HPKS___WMPASR_XWKP`
>  
> then repeated the split/stitch again,
>  
> `FXI_JIXS_L_IGI__CK_FWLPOSO_TWHK__MARXK` + `IXVIJG_RXIXELVOR_VOR_VOR_VOR_PS_WPS_WP`
>  
> I saw `VOR_VOR_VOR_VOR` again. There seemed to be some sort of nesting involved.
>  
> **The third major breakthrough** was observing that nested split/stitching `__P_IQT...` resulted in 
>  
> `_QJUUPAD_QJUUPAD`
>  
> **The fourth major breakthrough** was observing that, when we took the first of every two characters of every line, the result had no double spaces.
>  
> `XVDNDZ`
>  
> `_KHDU_PH`
>  
> `DUDUHZ`
>  
> `G_FOHDU`
>  
> `LD_IWGTTQH_W`
>  
> `HVS_ZONM_RCUJBEH_DKTG_`
>  
> `_PITTOZC_PITTOZC_PITTOZC_PITTOZ`
>  
> `FIXXIV_IJJIGX_SR_XLI_XIEGLIVVOR_VOR_VOR_VOR_O_`
>  
> `TZWSG_ZWYS_O_POBOBOGLANMH`
>  
> `_CBS_UWOBH_ZSOD_TCF_AOBYWBR_O`
>  
> `_P_EGDQATBDYH`
>  
> `BI`
>  
> `TG_EXV_VSLG`
>  
> `RRTHHUJAV_VX`
>  
> `RXWIF`
>  
> `DL_WRPRUU`
>  
> For a long time, however, this was a dead end.
>  
> **The fifth major breakthrough**
>  
> Then suddenly, by some fluke of the universe, I noticed that `PITTOZC` could shift to `QJUUPAD`.
>  
> And that both could shift to `BUFFALO`. 
>  
> BOOM. Something meaningful.
>  
> Googled "buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo". IT'S A THING.
>  
> **The sixth major breakthrough** was going through all the first-letter halves and seeing if I could shift them to anything meaningful. 
>  
> I *could*.
>  
> I found the following fragments:
>  
> `USAKA` (LUSAKA, ZAMBIA)
>  
> `HEAR_ME`
>  
> `ARARE` (HARARE, ZIMBABWE)
>  
> `D CLEAR`
>  
> `THE LAZY DOG`
>  
> `BUFFALO BUFFALO BUFFALO BUFFAL`
>  
> `BETTER_EFFECT_ON_THE_TEACHER`
>  
> `FLIES_LIKE_A_BANANA`
>  
> `ONE_GIANT_LEAP_FOR_MANKIND`
>  
> `A_PROBLEM`
>  
> `CCESSFUL`
>  
> `OUT`
>  
> **Seventh major breaththrough**
>  
> Lots of these were clearly fragments of mic-check phrases. The confirmation of this was realising that all of them other than the BUFFALO one were exactly the right length:
>  
> `THE_QUICK_BROWN_FOX_JUMPS_OVER_THE_LAZY_DOG`
>  
> `H_VFSU__ZDONNMMV__R_CYURJEBUEUHV_RDSKZTJGQ_`
>  
> `JAMES_WHILE_JOHN_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_HAD_A_BETTER_EFFECT_ON_THE_TEACHER`
>  
> `FRICX_XKIVV__OIFJRJWI_GLXV_PSORO_RXSL_IO_VX_IOETGRLWI_VHVPOKRS__V_O_RW_MVPOARS_RV_OXRW_KOP_`
>  
> `TIME_FLIES_LIKE_AN_ARROW_FRUIT_FLIES_LIKE_A_BANANA`
>  
> `T_ZLWPSFGC_HZ_WWYPSV_GO__GP_ODBUOLBOO_GULGAJNXMIH_`
>  
> `THAT'S_ONE_SMALL_STEP_FOR_A_MAN_ONE_GIANT_LEAP_FOR_MANKIND`
>  
> `_ACRB_SU_HUQWIOVBTHH_EZ'S_O_DU_UTDCVFG_TA_OPBPYOW_BDRB_POC`
>  
> `HOUSTON_WE_HAVE_A_PROBLEM`
>  
> `__PT_ZECGHDUQ_AITKBPDIYOH`
>  
> **Eighth major breakthrough**
>  
> If the original text hadn't had the mistake of the missing O of the last `BUFFALO`, I would have worked out sooner that the start of each of the fragments from Breakthrough Six was the end of each message.
>  
> **Ninth major breakthrough**
>  
> This took a very long time, but I finally cracked the exact process with writing out `CAN_YOU_HEAR_ME`. Up until now, I had noticed that there was some nesting, but I had always hit a dead-end getting to the bottom of it. I got lucky with this message because it happens to be the exact length required that there is no space on the last line, which would have skewed it.
>  
> `- CAN_YOU_HEAR_ME`
> `-        C        [Shift by B]`
> `-    A       N    [Shift by O]`
> `-  _   Y   O   U  [Shift by B]`
> `- _ H E A R _ M E [Shift by D]`
> `- __KOHZDDUP_BPVH`
>  
> From here, I was finally able to read the rest of the messages.

**One Last Thing To Do: Name of the Cipher**

> Using the cipher, BFTIODFTTWKBCSC decodes into SUNECVRYQLCQHZZ.
>  
> `- SUNECVRYQLCQHZZ`
> `-        T        [Shift by B]`
> `-    I       B    [Shift by O]`
> `-  F   D   W   S  [Shift by B]`
> `- B T O F T K C C [Shift by D]`
> `- BFTIODFTTWKBCSC`
>  
> You're telling me that the title uses a different cipher? Are you mental? If it is remotely as difficult and obscure as this cipher was, it will be basically impossible to work out using just one line. I have no idea. I have tried lots of things but can't make sense of it. I will update this and give credit to whoever figures this out.
>  
> Probably coincidentally, BFTIODFTTWKBCSC and PROJECTANACONDA are the same length and have the same letter frequency rates.

**Notes**

> 1. I entirely misinterpreted this clue:
>  
> "most likely some standard phrases will be used in the test conversations"
>  
> to mean that there would be some standard MILITARY phrases. But no, this meant mic check style phrases. I personally think it would be been a better puzzle if there had been a normal conversation happening.
>  
> 2. I tried for so long to think of what "BOIV" could turn into - sure, okay, good, done, true, yeah, etc - but never guessed "Haha".
>  
> 3. The last O in the last Buffalo is missing. It is unclear whether it went missing when writing the original message or writing its ciphertext, since it thankfully happens to be in the one location where it would have no effect on the result (the end).
>  
> 4. No idea what the rap clue is about. When I had only worked out the first four letters of the key, I thought the lyric format might be a clue and thought, hmmm, BOBD = Boulevard of Broken Dreams? Alas. Had a nice experience listening to some old bands again though.

Comment: This is an impressive solve! This puzzle has been right at the top of the list for upvoted unanswered questions on this site for *ages* - quite the scalp to claim. No wonder it took so long! Kudos. +1

Comment: @Stiv Thanks! Now just have to hope the asker checks in again at some point...

Comment: What took you soo long? :-)  No, really, impressive achievement!

Comment: I really like this answer.